# Eavesdropping on the alert dialog coming from the Android system java

Tags: java, android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTo77.jpg)
example

Example: I fetch the address alert dialog get system
I bring the body

Remember that not all system broadcasts can be intercepted or responded to in this way, and some broadcasts may require special permissions or system-level access. You should also be cautious with showing dialog boxes, as they can disrupt the user experience if overused. Ensure that your dialogs are informative and necessary.

Comment: I don't really see a question here. What exactly are you asking?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.